# Flutter Animation-start not working on second run

Tags: android, flutter, animation, curve

In my app/game I have this fan, it turnes around when you click on it, and then keeps going untill you click again. It works fine, with curves.easein etc.
But when ever you try to run it a second time *(or any number above 1 for that matter)* it skipes the initial start with a curve, and first begins when I run *repeat* after 2 seconds *(so it starts without the desired curve)*

Button code:

```
GestureDetector(
                       onTap: () {
                         Duration startStopTime = Duration(seconds: 3);
                         if(_animating) {
                           _rotationAnimationController.animateBack(1, duration: startStopTime, curve: Curves.easeOut);
                           setState(() {});
                         } else {
                           _rotationAnimationController.animateTo(1, duration: startStopTime, curve: Curves.easeInCubic);
                           Future.delayed(startStopTime, () {
                             _rotationAnimationController.repeat();
                           });
                         }
                         setState(() {
                           _animating = !_animating;
                         });
                       },
                       child: Padding(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
                         child: Container(
                           color: Colors.blue[300],
                           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/6*5,
                           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/6*5,
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
```

---

The fan widget:

```
IgnorePointer(
                       child: Container(
                         child: Transform.rotate(
                           angle: _animation.value,
                             child: Image.asset('assets/FanArms.png')
                         ),
                       ),
                   ),
```

---

The animation:

```
 var _animating = false;

  AnimationController _rotationAnimationController;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _rotationAnimationController = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 4 * pi ).animate(_rotationAnimationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _rotationAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

---

Here is a video of my the fan in my app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM6XW.jpg

> - Right when the fan stoppes, I click on it again, and it takes like 3 seconds before it starts *(and that's without the smooth curve)*

> And yea, my app is wierd, I know :)

Thaks allready :)

Comment: What if you remove `Future.delayed`?

Comment: The Future.delayed comes after the 'start' has played (I mean the start animation with the curve). Then as soon af that's done, the Future.delayed is starting with the repeating. But if I could make the repeat start with a curve, and then just keep going as normal, that would be great :) Also thr curve coule be in the init-state, the I'd have to use animationController.reverse to stop it. I just don't know how to do any of that.